# Symbolic solve in Octave isn't the same as in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math

I'm using the following OCTAVE command to solve an equation:

```
syms lambda
f = 0.9999999999999999614356461247534*lambda^8 + 0.010136594318889089056437488043559*lambda^7 + 0.000015602822908760063058460837969499*lambda^6 - 0.000000047482181730798751628339904656436*lambda^5 - 1.6804583575154387080270563605856e-10*lambda^4 - 1.9779236089667689638174134679895e-13*lambda^3 - 1.1091457134190232245774382079799e-16*lambda^2 - 2.9823717782777009154185183839051e-20*lambda - 3.202469692780878591525091765936e-24
solve(f==0, lambda)
```

The answer I get is

```
ans = {}(0x0)
```

On the other hand, when I try to use the same command in MATLAB, I get the following answer:

```
ans =
 0.0027518081408059183214532684717853 
-0.0075831287286429577224408168637228
- 0.00029575583281255452382838468617809 - 0.0001257455668418381216048479457788*i
- 0.0016381334730465236707629472401125 - 0.00001988265276086766636376330275894*i
- 0.0016381334730465236707629472401125 + 0.00001988265276086766636376330275894*i
- 0.00071874755966694673136475169368249 - 0.00019245511322083820223381924903732*i
- 0.00029575583281255452382838468617809 + 0.0001257455668418381216048479457788*i
- 0.00071874755966694673136475169368249 + 0.00019245511322083820223381924903732*i
```

Is there any way I can make OCTAVE's output equal to MATLAB's output, may be with some tweaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use sysm here:

```
c = [0.9999999999999999614356461247534,
     0.010136594318889089056437488043559,
     0.000015602822908760063058460837969499,
     - 0.000000047482181730798751628339904656436,
     - 1.6804583575154387080270563605856e-10,
     - 1.9779236089667689638174134679895e-13,
     - 1.1091457134190232245774382079799e-16,
     - 2.9823717782777009154185183839051e-20,
     - 3.202469692780878591525091765936e-24];

octave> format long
octave> roots (c)
ans =

    -0.00758312872864296 + 0.00000000000000000i
     0.00275180814080592 + 0.00000000000000000i
    -0.00163813347304650 + 0.00001988265276021i
    -0.00163813347304650 - 0.00001988265276021i
    -0.00071874755966697 + 0.00019245511322079i
    -0.00071874755966697 - 0.00019245511322079i
    -0.00029575583281256 + 0.00012574556684184i
    -0.00029575583281256 - 0.00012574556684184i
```

which gives the same roots as the other software product does